# How to order tag filtering search result

Tags: mysql, search-engine

I am building a search engine which support tag filter.below are the structure of my database which is many to many table

```
product_table
id   name
1     p1
2     p2
3     p3

tagged_table
id  pid   tid
1    1     1
2    1     2
3    1     3
4    1     4
5    1     5
6    2     1
7    2     2
8    3     1
9    3     2
10   3     4

tag_table
id tag_name
1    t1
2    t2
3    t3
4    t4
5    t5
```

- tagged_table.pid are referring to id of product_table
- tagged_table.tid are referring to id of tag_table

**How to build fastest sql query if i want the result return if any of the matches are found and order the result by the number of most case that matched?**

Comment: "The fastest" is a weird requirement when you don't have any. Try to solve your problem yourself and come back with something more particular, like a query that *works*

Comment: updated , i worrying about the performance because it go through a lots of query

Comment: so provide a query that doesn't fit your performance requirements, its `EXPLAIN` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for every table used in query

Comment: LOL! And google for many-to-many normalization (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model))

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation and correction, Do you mean my table is not really right?

Comment: yep, the current design is awful

Comment: @zerkms You just sent me back to school , i changed the structure of table and realize that my previous solution is not useful anymore , so i look for another solution which is updated in the question but have no idea how to order yet...Am i doing it right?

Comment: yep. And use `tid IN (1,2,3,4)` instead. PS: `select *` makes no sense with `GROUP BY`

Comment: Alright i think i got your solution ... thanks , I like the way you teaching , you must be a cool teacher

Comment: if only person want to be taught. It's often here that OP asks something and expects all the job will be done for him so that he could just copy-paste it in their project. In that case my bahaviour is treated as "rude" and "unhelpful"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to zerkms i changed my single table to 'many-many relation' table (refer to question)
And used a simple query to solve my question.

```
SELECT COUNT(pid) AS matches FROM tagged_table WHERE tid IN (1,2,3,4) ORDER BY matches DESC
```

Comment: `matches` should be enclosed in backticks ` not in quotes (if you want to enclose it, or just omit anithyng)